# extjs: open a new window when FormPanel submit function is used

Tags: extjs, window, submit, new-operator, formpanel

Heya,
i'm creating a Formpanel:

```
inputForm = new Ext.FormPanel({
    id:'inputForm',
    frame: true,
    closable:true,
    collapsible:true,
    renderTo:'somewhere',
    layout:'anchor',
    standardSubmit:true,
    method: 'post',
    items:[{ ... }]
)};
```

and use this submit button:

```
  text:'run',
  id: 'runButton',
  handler:function(){
         Ext.getCmp('inputForm').getForm().submit();
  }
```

how can i open the submit page in a new window/tab  ????

Comment: What do you mean by "submit" page? Is it just a page that says it was successful, or will it show some search results/information based on the user's form submission?

Comment: @jaitsu : maybe he want to submit the form to new window/tab like this `<form action='blablabla' method='post' target='_blank'>`

Comment: You'd be far better using the Ajax submit, and then on success opening a page

Answer (score 4):

Check this [sencha forum link](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?160475-Open-new-window-on-form-submit)

The relevant code snippet:

```
    form.submit({
        target : '_blank',
        url  : 'refdata/exportToXLS.do'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

have you fix your problem,.. because I see your question was 2 days ago..

this is how i define the form :

```
var inputForm = new Ext.FormPanel({
   id:'inputForm',
    method : "POST",
    url : "blablabla.php",
    items : [{...}]
    //standardSubmit : true // i do not need standardSubmit
});
```

and my button,

```
  text:'run',
  id: 'runButton',
  handler:function(){
     //Ext.getCmp('inputForm').getForm().submit();
     var form = Ext.getCmp('inputForm').getForm(); // or inputForm.getForm();
     var el = form.getEl().dom;
     var target = document.createAttribute("target");
     target.nodeValue = "_blank";
     el.setAttributeNode(target);
     el.action = form.url;
     el.submit(); 
  }
```